# mat expansion panel doesn't render inside mat card when used ngFor with formArray

Tags: angular, angular-material

When using formArray in mat accordion, the mat-expansion panel doesn't render, the card shows empty. But if I press next from the previous expansion panel the view renders.

project here:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pkrjzd

Comment: Did you even test your stackblitz? It doesn't work. Anyway, it's probably because pushing a new FormGroup to your FormArray doesn't run change detection. Try injecting ChangeDetectorRef and calling detectChanges() at the end of addExperience()

Comment: The stackblitz is working now, changeDetectorRef doesn't do anything.